# how to add new column to existing composite primary key

Tags: mysql

I have encountered a problem in that I already have a composite primary key in a MYSQL table. But now I have added another column to that table and due to some requirement changes, I have to modify that composite primary key in such a way that I need to add that previously mentioned column to that composite primary key list. Can anyone tell me how to alter that table without dropping existing composite primary key. I am doing this in a Rails project

Comment: Note that I have foreign keys to some of the columns that are in the composite primary key

Comment: A foreign key TO a partial primary key? That's bad mojo. You really should switch to an auto-increment primary key.

Comment: Dropping a key shouldn't drop the values - why can't you drop the PK?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can't alter the primary key.  You have to drop and re-add it:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable
  DROP PRIMARY KEY,
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (old_col1, old_col2, new_col);
```

Comment: This is the way to do it if there is something preventing you from dropping the primary key

Answer (score 1):

but if a key no exist? 
example:

```
ALTER TABLE xxxx ADD id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, ADD PRIMARY KEY(id,id2,id3);
```