# error when adding new entry to existing primary key sybase

Tags: sql, sybase, sap-ase

I have encountered a problem in sybase.

By searching in stackoverflow, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334792/how-to-add-new-column-to-existing-composite-primary-key) link.

But I found that incorrect in sybase, which gave me a syntax error warning.
Are there any other ways that can change the primary key in sybase?

Answer (score 0):

We can use sp_dropkey to drop the key and sp_primarykey to add the primary key.

`sp_dropkey primary, MyTable`

`sp_primarykey MyTable, col1, col2,..,col8`

Comment: Saying no primary key exist, while I create a table as specify the primary key

Comment: can you show table and column and create table query you used ?

Comment: ````create table S87EntityFolderMap (
 cty_cde                         CountryCode                      not null  ,
 entity                          Entity                           not null  ,
 folder                          Folder                           not null  ,
 PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( cty_cde, entity,folder )  on 'default' 
)````

Comment: for example, i want to add new column to this table and make it as one of primary key as well.

Answer (score 0):

1- Use :

```
sp_helpconstraint S87EntityFolderMap
```

To get your Primary Key system Generated name

2- Then use alter table to drop it :

```
alter table S87EntityFolderMap drop constraint name_from_first_step
```