# Can I add Primary Key with many condition

Tags: mysql

I've first table name "mustahik_perorangan" and the second name "data_mustahik"

mustahik perorangan have 4 primary key and foreign key in another table 
like this condition

```
PRIMARY KEY (`mustahik_nik`,`ins_provinces_code`,`ins_cities_code`,`ins_institution_types_code`,`ins_institution_serial_no`),
 KEY `fk_reference_6` (`ins_provinces_code`,`ins_cities_code`,`ins_institution_types_code`,`ins_institution_serial_no`),
 CONSTRAINT `FK_ins_musper` FOREIGN KEY (`ins_provinces_code`, `ins_cities_code`, `ins_institution_types_code`, `ins_institution_serial_no`) REFERENCES `baznasgo_s_organization`.`institutions` (`provinces_code`, `cities_code`, `institution_types_code`, `institution_serial_no`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

and i want to add primary to table mustahik_perorangan, so mustahik perorangan have 5 primary key ?

but i can't do it because it condition..

```
ALTER TABLE mustahik_perorangan ADD idc INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,ADD PRIMARY KEY (`idc`);
```

May you know to do it ?

Comment: Holy crap[.](http://www.google.com)

Comment: composite primary key, and he want to add more..

Comment: What was the error message?

Comment: i bet its conflicting pk, he should drop the old one and rebuilt the pk.. i suppose.

Comment: What do you mean by having five primary keys, and does this even make sense?

Comment: yes, the suggest is that .. but so many foreign key there :( @BagusTesa

Comment: look, if you dig deeper in SOF, you can find [some insight](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334792/how-to-add-new-column-to-existing-composite-primary-key) @Tara

Comment: wait..... @KiranKumar

Comment: #1068 - Multiple primary key defined @KiranKumar

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ALTER TABLE to add a composite primary key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8859353/alter-table-to-add-a-composite-primary-key)

Comment: i cant drop pk because have foreign key .. the foreign key cant drop

Comment: may you know solution ?

Comment: I'd ***HIGHLY*** recommend you use a normal, numeric, auto incremented primary key and instead declare a multi-part `unique` key. Otherwise explain the problem you're trying to solve with a 5-part primary key and maybe we can find a better solution.

Comment: Somebody needs a class or good book on SQL and data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A table can have at most *one* primary key constraint.

The primary key constraint can contain multiple columns. We refer to that as a *composite* key.

---

It is possible to add a new column.

It's also possible to add a UNIQUE constraint on the column and specify `AUTO_INCREMENT` attribute on the column.

As an example:

```
  ALTER TABLE mustahik_perorangan
    ADD idc INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
  , ADD UNIQUE KEY (`idc`)
```

---

It's also possible to a sixth column to the existing composite primary key. But I don't think this is what you really want.

As a demonstration of how to add a column to an existing composite primary key, I'll provide an example.

Note that the primary key must be dropped and re-added. And a UNIQUE key must be added for the AUTO_INCREMENT column.

Assuming there are no foreign keys referencing the primary key of this table.

```
  ALTER TABLE mustahik_perorangan
    DROP PRIMARY KEY
  , ADD idc INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
  , ADD UNIQUE KEY (`idc`)
  , ADD PRIMARY KEY
    (`mustahik_nik`
    ,`ins_provinces_code`
    ,`ins_cities_code`
    ,`ins_institution_types_code`
    ,`ins_institution_serial_no`
    ,`idc`
    )
```

If there are foreign keys referencing the table, the change is a little more involved. (Did you want an additional column added to the foreign keys in the referencing tables?)

It's not entirely clear what you are attempting to achieve.

Comment: I just know unique can be auto increment ..  the important is .. i want to add id with auto increment to using  SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() .. 
thank you so much @spencer7593

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add the primary key, but in your case, you need to drop pk and then add new pk, otherwise the engine interpretes as you are trying to add multiple pks, the multiple pks are different from composite pk, you can add composite pk, but you can't add multiple pks

`alter table xx drop primary key, add primary key(k1, k2, k3);`

Comment: yes thank you @kiran kumar .. but if i drop ..I had a long way to do ..  because foreign key so many